# Use elements from a predefined list as variables on a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, json, list, d3.js

I have a predefined list which is the next one:

```
let services_list = ["SUCURSALES_BANCA_COMERCIAL", "SUCURSALES_BANCA_DE_DESARROLLO",
"SUCURSALES_SOCAP","SUCURSALES_SOFIPO", "CORRESPONSALES", "CAJEROS_AUTOMÁTICOS",
"TERMINALES_PUNTO_DE_VENTA", "ESTABLECIMIENTOS_CON_TPV"]
```

And then I have the following function:

```
let state = document.getElementById("stateDrop").value
let example = []
d3.json("../api_states").then(function(data){
    data.forEach(function(d){
        if(d.ENTIDAD === parseInt(state)){
         services_list.forEach(function(f){
            example.push(d.f)
         })
        }
    })
})
```

What I want is to enter each element of the predefined list, and use that element as a variable in the `example.push` part. So the data would contain something like

```
{"SUCURSALES_BANCA_COMERCIAL":10}
```

So instead of typing every key I would like to access it with the mentioned list, however the `(d.f)` part is not recognized.

I hope I make myself clear.

Comment: what is the `10` in your 3rd code block? is it from the api?

Comment: Use bracket notation: `example.push(d[f])`.

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD the 10 was just the plain value for that key that I wanted to push.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado that was it! It was so simple yet I didn't figure it out. If you can post it as an answer I will mark it as solved!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the variable `f` is the string and `d` is the number like

```
// { f: d } 
{"SUCURSALES_BANCA_COMERCIAL":10}
```

You can do this in your code

```
.
.
    data.forEach(function(d){
        if(d.ENTIDAD === parseInt(state)){
         services_list.forEach(function(f){
            const obj = {};
            obj[f] = d;
            example.push(obj);
         })
        }
    })
.
.
```

so your example array would have elements with key-value pairs